# How to make use of log4j.properties of application root when using `gradle run`

Tags: java, gradle, log4j, classpath

When using `gradle run` on a project that uses Log4J I see the following errors.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (gma.api.GmaApi).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I've been able to confirm that this warning is due to Log4J not being able to find my log4j.properties file which is in the root of the application. To determine this I've set `_JAVA_OPTIONS` to `-Dlog4j.debug` as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6076955/83658) which gave me detailed debug information into the resolution of log4j.properties. I confirmed this also by placing my log4j.properties file into the more conventional `src/main/resources` directory which made this warnings go away and also resulted in the expected logging output.

What I would like is to keep `log4j.properties` in the application root directory and have it picked up by Log4J. My understanding of how to do this is to add it to the "classpath" however I'm not sure how to do this from my project.gradle file so that it is picked up when using the gradle [Run task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html).

Answer (score 0):

After stumbling through the documentation and various forum posts I arrived at the concept of a [source set](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet:resources) which appears to be useful for teaching Gradle where your resources are located. Since I was interested including only a single file `log4j.properties` I also needed [the advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24226217/83658) on how to achieve that with filters so that my whole application root doesn't become a source application resources.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
        // Used to pick up log4j.properties resource at the root of the applicatoin directory
        resources {
            srcDir '.'
            include 'log4j.properties'
        }
    }
}
```

There may be other and perhaps more effective ways of solving this problem but this is the first one that I found that works for me.